# Why can't I manually pass a ViewModel to a webapi controller through manipulating the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, query-string

My WebApi Controller named `SrchController`, has the following proof-of-concept action/method listed below.

I want to call this method/action (not sure what to call it) by manipulating the url. for testing purposes.  So I was under the impression this would use model binding.

I was expecting the value of criteria to be set coming into the method if I typed in the browser address `[mysiteroot]/api/srch/TestResults?criteria.name = "hello"`

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<ParcelResultItemViewModel> TestResults(SimpleViewModel criteria)
{
    //check value of criteria....it is always null. <-- i'm expecting name = "hello"
    //do stuff here
    return something;
}
```

my question is closely related to this question [How to handle optional query string parameters in Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064439/how-to-handle-optional-query-string-parameters-in-web-api)  Darin states that it should work as I expect. What could be wrong?

### webapi routes

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }

            );    
        }
```

## Update

I'm not receiving any error messages, the value of the viewmodel being passed to the method is simply null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url parameters should be named after properties of `SimpleViewModel` class, `criteria` part here is not needed. Besides, query string is constructed in a different way - without double quotes and spaces.

All in all, here is how the url should look like:

```
[mysiteroot]/api/srch/TestResults?name=hello
```

or, in case of multiple parameters:

```
[mysiteroot]/api/srch/TestResults?name=hello&address=someaddress
```

That is, again, assuming that `SimpleViewModel` has properties `name` and `address` (not case specific of course). From server side everything looks OK, so as soon as you will start to use correct URL, everything should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I must have some other code that is affecting this.  Because, I cannot call my webapi method by manually entering the url with proprerty values and have it instantiate a ViewModel object. Can you think of anywhere I should start looking? could bad or conflicting webapi/mvc routes cause this?

Comment: @Mr.Manager, in ASP.NET MVC everything starts from routing. Can you please show your api routes registration? Also it would be great to know what result you are getting. Is it 404 Not found, or 500 internal error, or anything else?